# How can I deal with the inability to speak caused by the pink bubbles Wild Magic surge effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, wild-magic

One of the effects on the Wild Magic Surge chart is:

> You can't speak for the next minute. Whenever you try, pink bubbles float out of your mouth.

This effect put me out of practically an entire fight because my spells have verbal components.  Is it possible to use the Subtle Spell metamagic and *dispel magic* together to cure me of the voiceless affliction?

Answer (score 14):

**TL;DR:** you can subtly *dispel magic*. Whether or not that solves your bubble problem is a [contested question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/75964/23970).

### Yes. Subtle Spell will allow you to cast even while "enbubbled."

Subtle Spell allows you to cast a spell--at the cost of a sorcery point--without providing the somatic (gesture) and *verbal* component(s) of the spell.

Since you don't need to provide the verbal component, the bubbles don't interfere with your provision of that component, and you're good to go. As long as you've got sorcery points to spend.

### Then maybe you could *dispel magic* the effect (via Subtle Spell) to be free of the bubbles.

As [the accepted answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/75965/23970) attests, you can dispel the pink bubble effect. And as *dispel magic* itself has a verbal component, you of course need to Subtly cast it (as above).

However, [this later answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/84793/23970) makes what I think is a good argument--supported by Sage Advice--that *dispel magic* will not remove the pink bubble effect.