# How do spell components work in regards to the UA Psionic Soul Sorcerer's Psychic Sorcery ability?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, unearthed-arcana, spell-components, metamagic

The UA Psionic Soul Sorcerer has the following Psionic Talent option:

> Psychic Sorcery. When you cast a spell, you can use your mind to form it, rather than relying on words, gestures, and materials. To do so, roll your Psionic Talent die. The spell then requires no verbal component, and **if** you rolled the level of the spell or higher, **the spell doesn’t require somatic or material components either.**

(Emphasis Mine)

This strikes me as confusing due to how the player's handbook describes spell components

> A spell's components are the physical requirements you must meet in order to cast it. Each spell's description indicates whether it requires verbal (V), somatic (S), or material (M) components. If you can't provide one or more of a spell's components, you are unable to cast the spell

I had assumed that you needed to be able to provide the components before attempting to cast the spell, but the wording on the subtle spell metamagic begs to differ

> When you cast a spell, you can spend 1 sorcery point to cast it without any somatic or verbal components.

According to [This Answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84780/how-can-i-deal-with-the-inability-to-speak-caused-by-the-pink-bubbles-wild-magic/84781#84781) this metamagic allows you to cast it without being able to provide the components if you cast it using the subtle spell metamagic. However, comparing this to the UA we see a problem. The psychic sorcery ability activates at the same time, but isn't guaranteed to make the spell castable necessarily, so that brings me to my question

**Can you attempt to cast a spell without having the needed components by using this psionic talent option, and if you don't succeed on the roll and find yourself needing to provide components that you can't provide, what happens to the casting?**

(Note additionally that if you cast a lv 1 spell or a cantrip it's functionally guaranteed to succeed by not from a rules perspective if that matters to the answer)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the spell "Creation"

> Using any material created by this spell as another spell's material component causes that spell to fail.

Note that this doesn't say you cannot attempt to cast the spell, it says it fails. An important note also is that you could also run into a situation in which the caster was incorrect about a component. Maybe your eye of newt was actually an eye of gecko.

What happens if a spell fails? Well according to counterspell the action and spell slot are consumed with no effect.

I think the only inconsistency is the interpretation of :

> If you can't provide one or more of a spell's components, you are unable to cast the spell.

You have presumed that this means you cannot attempt the spell, however I think it is more fitting to consider that it means the spell fails. This also means it handles the situation in which you had the components when you attempt to cast a spell but lose them during the cast (through a reaction or the such removing the component).

In the end I think it will be up to the DM as none of these are clear cut enough to say 100% As written this is what happens. But I think the closest as written answer is: You can attempt to cast a spell without the components (either through hope of feature fixing it, or ignorance of lacking the correct component) however if nothing happens to meet the requirements, then the spell fails, action and spell slot are lost.