# Can a Wild Magic Sorcerer counterspell his own Wild Magic Surge?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, counterspelling, wild-magic

Similar to [Counterspell & Dispel Magic vs Wild Magic Surge](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104087/counterspell-dispel-magic-vs-wild-magic-surge), but more specific.

According to the most-upvoted answer to the linked question above, a Wild Magic Surge can be countered if the effect is actually the casting of a spell. Is there anything in the rules that prevents a sorcerer from countering his own Wild Magic Surge spell?

I.e. If I am playing a sorcerer and accidentally cast fireball centered on myself, can I counterspell it and avoid the ensuing tragedy, assuming I have the spell and a slot available?

In the broader sense, I suppose I'm asking if there's anything that prevents a spellcaster from counterspelling their own spell, but this is probably the most likely scenario for wanting to do such a thing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming you meet all the prerequisites, you can counterspell your own spell.

These are:

- you have counterspell prepared or known as applicable
- you have your reaction available
- you have a spell slot of the appropriate level available
- you are within 60 feet of yourself (probably a given but could be complicated by using a familiar etc.)
- you are a creature (also probably a given)
- you can see yourself (you might be invisible or working thru an out of sight familiar)

Comment: I think we can waive the visibility requirement in this specific case.  You are fully aware of your own body without having to specifically see it.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym Really?  Hold your left hand up fingers splayed. Close your eyes. With your right index finger rapidly touch your nose, your left thumb, your nose, your left index finger etc. Still think you are "fully aware of your own body without having to see it"?

Comment: I'm at least as aware of my body as I am of seeing somebody else.  I may not be able to juggle blind, but I can poke myself in the chest without failure. If seeing somebody in poor light or through thick fog is good enough for counterspell targeting purposes, knowing your chest exists directly between your arms is good enough, too.

Comment: @DaleM Tried your exercise. No problem touching all body parts in rapid succession. Is this hard for some folks?

Comment: @keithcurtis it was a pretty easy exercise for me too.

Answer (score 6):

### Yes, because you can target yourself

PHB 204 states that spells that target a creature can also target yourself:

> If a spell targets a creature of your choice, you can choose yourself, unless the creature must be hostile or specifically a creature other than you.

Counterspell targets a specific creature and does not have those requirements:

> You attempt to interrupt a creature in the process of Casting a Spell.

Therefore, you can use your reaction on your own turn to counterspell your own wild magic surge, because you are casting a spell.

Answer (score -3):

I'd say, no, a Wild Magic Sorcerer can't counter his own surge. The table states that as a result of a surge you cast a spell. Since Counterspell needs to happen at the same time (you cast it while someone is casting the spell you want to counter). And since you can't cast two spells at the same time this would be impossible.

Comment: Welcome to the stack! Most spells are cast using an action, but counter spell is cast as a reaction.  Doesn't wild magic surge take effect after the casting of the spell that triggered it?

Comment: The [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=13) clearly demonstrates how you can *counterspell* an enemy's *counterspell* of your own spell: "Cornelius the wizard is casting *fireball* on his turn, and his foe casts *counterspell* on him. Cornelius also has *counterspell* prepared, so he uses his reaction to cast it and break his foe’s *counterspell* before it can stop *fireball*." Basically, *counterspell* occurs after a spell's casting but before the effect - you're not casting two spells at the same time, but rather one after the other.

Comment: Related: [Counterspelling a counterspell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62217/counterspelling-a-counterspell) - and two questions marked as duplicates of it: [Can a caster Counterspell a Counterspell against a non-cantrip spell they cast?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102158/can-a-caster-counterspell-a-counterspell-against-a-non-cantrip-spell-they-cast), [Can you perform a reaction to somebody else's reaction?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70236/can-you-perform-a-reaction-to-somebody-elses-reaction)